# Django google app engine No such file or directory

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I have a Django 2.x with python 3.6 site in Google Cloud, the app is in app engine flex. (my first app :)

My app has an upload page, where I am asking the user upload a JSON file (that is never kept in the site), what I do is open it and generate another file from it

I know that django depending on the size of the file it goes into memory but I was never able to use this functionality, so what I did in local env, was creating a folder that I called, temp_reports, so I created the files here, uploaded them into a bucket and then deleted them, from temp_reports.

So I was thinking, as the site is already in gcloud, if I can directly create these files into the bucket? or do I still need to generate them in the site and then upload them?

Now if it is from my site I keep getting the following error:

Exception Value:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vmagent/app/temp_reports/file_516A3E1B80334372ADB440681BB5F030.xlsx
```

I had in my app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /temp_reports
  static_dir: temp_reports
```

Is there something I am missing? in order to use temp_reports?

Or how can I create a file directly into my bucket?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use the Storage Bucket without having to upload the file manually. This can be done by Google Cloud Storage client library (Preferred Method) . It allows you to store and retrieve data directly from the Storage Bucket.  Secondly, you can use Cloud Storage API to do the same functionality but requires more efforts to set it up.

You want to use the upload_from_string method from google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.

```
    upload_from_string(data, content_type='text/plain', client=None, 
    predefined_acl=None)
```

So to create a text file directly on the bucket you could do this:

```
     storage_client = storage.Client()
     bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(‘mybucket’)
     blob = bucket.blob(‘mytextfile.txt’)
     blob.upload_from_string('Text file contents', content_type='text/plain')
```

For more information you can refer to the following page:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string